# How to get Product via API right after product created?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, rest-api

Case : When product is created, I need to send SKU to 3rd party, and then they immediately call magento REST API to get product by SKU.

So far I'm using `catalog_product_save_after` event. And for testing purpose I call v1/products/{sku} inside observer.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
     $product = $observer->getProduct();
     if($product->isObjectNew()){
       $ch = curl_init("http://xxx.xxx/index.php/rest/V1/products/".$product->getSku());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . xxx));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
     }
}
```

Observer is working fine and I can get $product.

However, unfortunatelly the result for calling rest api is error `"message":"Requested product doesn't exist"`. But when i tried to call `v1/products/{sku}` with same SKU as before after few seconds, I got the product.

Is there any way to get what i want with that flow? Or I need to use another event?

Answer (score 1):

`catalog_product_save_after` is fired in scope of product save DB transaction. So the product is not actually persisted to the database yet, when it is requested via web API.

Preferred extension mechanism in Magento 2 is [plugins](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html). When 'after' plugin is invoked, product transaction should already be committed, so your case should pass.